# My php quiz is not writing the user's grade to a separate file. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm having an issue getting my php quiz to write what the user's grade to a separate file. It shows how many they got right/wrong but it does not write that to a file. What is wrong with my code in here that would would prevent that, or am I missing something? Something constructive input would be helpful.

```
<?php
session_start();
#error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('connect.php');
require_once "lib.php";
require_once "utils.php";
$quiz_done = true;
if(isset($_SESSION['active']))
{
    $EmailAddress = $_SESSION['EmailAddress'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE EmailAddress='$EmailAddress'";

    if($Results = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Results, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $UserID = $row['UserID'];
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;
        }
    }
    echo $UserID;
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM Quiz WHERE UserID='$UserID'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql1);
    if($result1)
    {
        while($record = mysqli_fetch_row($result1))
        {
            if($record == $UserID)
            {
                $quiz_done=true;                    
                $sql="DELETE FROM Quiz WHERE UserID='$UserID'";
                $Results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            }
            else
            {
                $quiz_done=false;                   
            }
     }
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Quiz</title>
   </head>
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
   <body class="body">
      <div id='wrapper'>
      <div id="header">
         <br>
         <h1> PHP Learning Course! </h1>
         </br>
         <?php include_once "left.php" ?>
      </div>
      <div id="quiz">
      <div id="quiz_name">
         <h3>PHP Learning Quiz</h3>
      </div>
      <p>
      <div id='quiz1_form'>
<?php
#function func($quiz_done)
#{
#    if($quiz_done == true && $SESSION['q_No'] > 0)
#    {
#        header("Location: results.php");
#    }
#}
    echo <<<EOT
   <FORM name="quiz" id="myQuiz" method="post" action="results.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="quiz_no">
   Firstname:<input type="text" name="fname">
   Lastname:<input type="text" name="lname">
   <br>
   <pre>
   01. PHP is a closed source software.
   </pre>
   True<INPUT type="radio" name="Q1" value="True">
   False<INPUT type="radio" name="Q1" value="False">
   </br>

   <br>
   <pre>
   02. PHP is a sever-side scription language?
   </pre>
   True<INPUT type="radio" name="Q2" value="True">
   False<INPUT type="radio" name="Q2" value="False">
   </br>

   <br>
   <pre>
   03. PHP does not support databases?
   </pre>
   True<INPUT type="radio" name="Q3" value="True">
   False<INPUT type="radio" name="Q3" value="False">
   </br>

   <br>
   <pre>
   04. PHP can run on different platforms ( Ex, Windows, Linux, and Unix)?
   </pre>
   True<INPUT type="radio" name="Q4" value="True">
   False<INPUT type="radio" name="Q4" value="False">
   </br>

   <br>
   <pre>
   05. You can use forms to take input from the user and store that information in a database or file?
   </pre>
   True<INPUT type="radio" name="Q5" value="True">
   False<INPUT type="radio" name="Q5" value="False">
   </br>

   <p>
   <input id="subbut" type="submit" value="Submit FORM">
   <INPUT ID="subbut" TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear FORM">
   </p>
   </form>
EOT;
?>
</p>
</div>
</div>  <!-- end main div -->
</div>  <!-- end wrapper div -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refrain from asking the `"What is wrong with my code"` kind of questions. Start by turning on error reporting at the top of your script `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. If there are errors, update your post to show said errors and the code associated. Don't just dump all of your code here and expect us to understand what's what. We do this to help people (aka, you), not simply solve your issues for you! (*Don't take it personally, let us help you by you helping us :)* )

Comment: Where in that code are you writing to a file?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing there to even write a file there. I'd look into

```
public function writeGrade(){
        $content  = "".$userid." Results";
        $content .= "".$YourGradeVariable."";
        $content .="\r\n";
        $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/".$userid.".txt","wb");
        fwrite($fp,$content);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

That's pretty general, but you should be able to customize that to suite your needs.